# Rasterstack of temperature data with numeric value in R

Tags: r, integer, raster, numeric

i want to do some tests with my rasterdata in R. I need numeric values. But R shows me only integers. How can i change this? Any idea? Thanks in advance :D

```
#libraries
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)

    setwd("C:/Users/cathe/Documents/Cropped_raster")

    ## polygon with crop-extend ##
    shp <- readOGR("C:/Users/cathe/OneDrive/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/CLC2000_shapefiles/CLC2000_Nichtdurchgängig städtische Prägung.shp")

    ## load tif files ##
    infiles = list.files(path=getwd(),
                     pattern="*.tif$|*.TIF$")


    ## Filenames with desired suffix and output place ##
    outfiles = file.path("C:/Users/cathe/Documents/Cropped_raster_nicht_durchgängig",
                     paste0(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(infiles)),
                            ".tif"))
    outfiles[outfiles == -9999] <- NA #alle -9999 auf NA setzen, wenn nötig



    ## crop and output settings (compression and datatype)
    for (i in seq_along(infiles)) {
      r = crop(stack(infiles[i]), shp)
      writeRaster(r, filename=outfiles[i],
              bylayer=FALSE,
              format="GTiff",
              datatype="numeric",
              options="COMPRESS=ZIP",
              x, NAflag=-9999,
              overwrite=TRUE)
    }
```

Comment: @JonasV: Thanks. The datavalues are numeric. I loaded them in ArcGIS to check the datatype. Is there any possibility to change the values into numeric?

Comment: If you only have whole numbers without decimal places use INT4S, if your rasters have decimal places use FLT4S. Those are safe bets. Also try and read up on the difference between integers and float numbers. It will help you make decisions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in the `datatype` argument of `writeRaster()`.
From the documentation:

> datatype: Character. Output data type (e.g. 'INT2S' or 'FLT4S'). See
> dataType. If no datatype is specified, 'FLT4S' is used, unless this
> default value was changed with rasterOptions

Numeric only exists in the R world. Outside you have integers and floats, what you need depends on your data.